# HHVM with FastCGI install error

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, fastcgi, hhvm

I'm getting below error when I try to install using `apt-get install -y --force-yes hhvm-fastcgi`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hhvm-fastcgi : Depends: hhvm (>= 2.3.0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also did `apt-get install hhvm` but I'm getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
hhvm is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

Is there a way to get this `fastcgi` working with `HHVM`?

Answer (score 2):

As of the 3.0.0 release, there is no longer a `hhvm-fastcgi` package. Instead, the `hhvm` only supports FastCGI. You can find instructions on how to install that package for your distro [here](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki#installing-pre-built-packages-for-hhvm).

Once it has been successfully installed, it'll provide a short blurb on some commands that will then go and configure your web server (either Nginx or Apache) to use HHVM, or you can follow almost any `php-fpm` installation instructions, just replacing `php-fpm` with `hhvm`.

If you don't get the blurb (as you're already running the latest version), you can see it [here](https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/blob/master/hhvm/deb/skeleton/DEBIAN/postinst#L11-L28).

Answer (score 1):

> As per the [official documentation](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-Packages-on-Ubuntu-12.04), we'll install HHVM, which also
>   includes the ability to start HHVM with FastCGI.

**Pre-requisites**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y unzip vim git-core curl wget build-essential python-software-properties
```

**Installing HHVM**

```
$ wget -O - http://dl.hhvm.com/conf/hhvm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu precise main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y hhvm
```

You can also try to do this before installing HHVM:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:mapnik/boost
```

---

Additional:

[This page](http://hhvm.com/blog/3203/nightly-packages) has a comment about a vagrant box that comes pre installed with HHVM.

If you are interested: [HHVM-Vagrant](https://github.com/vicb/hhvm-vagrant)

Comment: I've already tried the link in official documentation. I'm also using Vagrant

Comment: Which distro and version are you using?

Comment: What does `apt-cache search hhvm` give you?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper you might also want to re run all the commands in order. Just to make sure :)

Comment: hhvm - HHVM virtual machine, runtime, and JIT for the PHP language
hhvm-dbg - HHVM virtual machine, runtime, and JIT for the PHP language
hhvm-fastcgi - The package provides FastCGI support for HHVM. HHVM is a high-performance just-in-time compiled PHP runtime. FastCGI is a protocol that allows language interpreters to run behind web servers.
hhvm-nightly - HHVM virtual machine, runtime, and JIT for the PHP language
hhvm-nightly-dbg - HHVM virtual machine, runtime, and JIT for the PHP language

Comment: I ran all of them in order

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper Aaah I see. Can you check which version is installed?

Comment: It's hhvm version 3.0.1

Comment: Can you try to un install everything too? `purge --autoremove`?